# How to remove sudo dependency of a github project for Travis CI?

Tags: mongodb, github, elasticsearch, travis-ci, sudo

I have a project on github, that contains a `.travis.yml` file with a `before_install` hook to do things that require `sudo`. To move the project to `container type infrastructure` I have to remove the sudo dependency of the project. Question is - how?

On this page of Travis CI documentation, in the `before_install` section they're providing scripts to run in this hook:
http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/installing-dependencies/

However those scripts depend on `sudo` which I'm trying to get rid of. What are possible workaround for this? I still need to have the scripts run, but they won't without `sudo`.

Thanks.

---

**Edit:**

Had to replace most of the data with `X`s, but you can still get the idea os what's happening in the code:

```
  - "sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://xxxxxxxx.ubuntu.com:XX --recv XXXXXX"
  - "echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist XXgen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.x/xxx.list"
  - "sudo apt-get update"
  - "sudo apt-get install mongodb-org-server"
  - curl -O https://download.xxxxxx.org/xxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxx-X.X.X.deb && sudo dpkg -i --force-confnew xxxxxx-X.X.X.deb
  - sudo service xxxxxx start && sleep 10
```

As you can see, there are multiple `sudo` calls that need to be cleared up.

---

**Edit:**

I need to install **ElasticSearch 1.7** and **MongoDB 2.6**

Comment: Can you post your `.travis.yml`? Might be able to offer alternatives for what you're installing. Also check out http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/migrating-from-legacy/

Comment: @Kristján Added to question. Thanks.

Comment: What is the service that is `xxxxx` out? I fear you may have added too much munging to this question to answer it.